# using awk to append a file with data from multiple files

Tags: awk

I have a file of 298 lines and 2 columns (file1). I have 48 other files of varying length (2-298 lines) with 6 columns where columns 1 and 2 would be in common with file1. I want to append file1 by pasting the data from column 4 from files 2-50 only where both columns match from file 1, so that the final appended file will contain columns 1&2 from file1 and the next 48 columns from files 2-50 (a 298 lined file with 50 columns). I want NA if value is not found in files 2-50.

file1:

```
1   1234
1   48687
2   1234
2   987365
3   97857
```

file2:

```
1   12  234 57
1   1234    3547    72
2   1234    245 17
```

file3:

```
1   1234    249 10
1   48687   250 9
```

appended file

```
1   1234    72  10  file4   file5....
1   48687   NA  9   file4   file5...
```

Comment: Use `join` rather than awk.  Details later (if I find time.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash    
fn=($(awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=1; i<=49;i++) {print "file"i}}'))
awk -f a.awk ${fn[@]} > append.txt
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
    N=ARGC-2
}
{
    key=$1 OFS $2
}
NR==FNR {
    a[key]++
    next
}
FNR==1 {j++}
{
    b[key,j]=$4
}
END {
    for (i in a) {
        printf "%s%s", i, OFS
        for (j=1;j<=N;j++) {
            printf "%s",(b[i,j]=="")?"NA":b[i,j]
            printf "%s",(j==N)?ORS:OFS
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the assignment of fn: `fn=(file{1..49})`

Comment: I will give it a try, with the additional suggestion, do I just simply substitute the entire 1st line fn=($....) with William's fn=(file{1..49})?

Comment: I gave it a try with the 1st part as a shell script and the second part saved as a.awk.  I got an appended file, however, it seems to only have 47 of the 48 appended columns.  It seems to not write the data of the first of the 48 files. Is there an explanation why that happened? Also the original column order (from the append file) is not the same after the script ran, not really a problem; just curious. Finally, if I want to now write a file with data from column 6, do I just change b[key,j]=$4 to b[key,j]=$6 ?  Thanks

Comment: @user3146560 The column order is not guaranteed when using associative arrays.. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays The file should have all columns, the data from the first file is in the variable `i` in `printf "%s%s", i, OFS`..

Comment: @user3146560 For the last question: Yes, you just change `$4` to `$6`. Hope this helps :)